# Android: expand animation not working

Tags: android, animation

I am using following code to animate expandable layout:

```
class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
    private View _view;
    private int _startHeight;
    private int _finishHeight;

    public ExpandAnimation( View view, int startHeight, int finishHeight ) {
        _view = view;
        _startHeight = startHeight;
        _finishHeight = finishHeight;
        setDuration(500);
        System.out.println(_startHeight);
        System.out.println(_finishHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation( float interpolatedTime, Transformation t ) {
        int newHeight = (int)((_finishHeight - _startHeight) * interpolatedTime + _startHeight);
        _view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        _view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize( int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight ) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds( ) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This animation is created every time I click a button. It is called properly (checked System.out.println and it prints correct values) however in emulator animation runs only like once of 15 times. To be exact hiding it works great but expanding works only once a few times (on emulator, cant get it working on phone).

What could be the problem?

Thanks in forward

**EDIT:** layout I am trying to animate is FrameLayout. It has TextView as child and finishHeight is measured by textView measure height. The values are correct. I have also tried calling textView.requestLayout() in apply transformation to redraw layout but it is not working. It still expands only sometimes. If you need any more code feel free to ask.

Comment: I have enlarged clickable areas a lot and it works better on phone but it still isnt 100%. Sometimes my phone recognizes that I clicked on 2 items and it expands them both. But I think they are large enough now (like 1,2 cm) ... realy dont know how to make this work better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling

```
((View) toExpand.getParent()).invalidate();
```

just after startAnimation solved my problem. Must check it on other devices but I think it will work.